# Link is removing Http header

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to do a simple thing , navigate to an external url

```
  <a href="http://18.217.228.108/angularapp1/book/"> Class Books  </a>
```

However I am getting a 404 because the Http// portion is being deleted I am not sure if this is an mvc thing or html thing. Here is link http://18.217.228.108/angularapp1.
Here is a link to a screen shot of me accessing url

https://gyazo.com/455b01f1ceded24f9b4ce6c58b0e10e1

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50574593/link-is-removing-http-header">Anchor Test</a>
```

and then try keying `http://18.217.228.108/angularapp1/book/` into your browser url.

The link you are using is actually 404.

*Based on the link given in updated question:*

The new link you've given is an html page (which you can navigate to in the "normal way"). It links to an angular app with an anchor "Books". Clicking on "Books", whilst attaching "book/" to the url in the browser (the url you're trying to link to in your original question), is intercepted by the script and actually navigates to:

```
http://13.59.126.130/BuellerWebApi_deploy/api/book/getAll
```

which returns a `Json` object containing data to display on the same page.

(Your concern about the removal of the `http://` in the anchor is a red-herring (try navigating to `http://www.bbc.com` - you will see `www.bbc.com` in the browser `url`). It's the way your app has been configured.)

So, as things stand, navigating to the anchor in your original question, whilst appearing to be a valid url, actually is not. Its a 404.

Comment: Is that on a local machine or published? I cannot access the url you gave from the browser, which suggests it not published and not an external url

Comment: OK, I see the link you gave navigates to a page which, in turn, navigates to the anchor you're trying to navigate to. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Curious-programmer,

You must navigate using an absolute URL just when it is out of your domain such as https://www.amazon.com/
However, I've noticed that you are trying to navegate to a link inside your own domain using absolute URL when you must use relative URL like:

```html
<a href="/angularapp1/book/"> Class Books  </a>
```